# What are the 4 values passed in shape for ndarray in numPy?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

What is the meaning of:
shape=(1, 224, 224, 3)

I mean what are all the values specifying given here for shape?

Comment: If you are using machine learning for images, then `(batch, image_width, image_height, RGB_dims) = (1,224,224,3)`

Answer (score 1):

When the shape is of length 4, it means that that you have a "4D-tensor". A 4D-tensor is a group of 3D-tensor. For instance if `A` is a 4D-tensor, `A[0]` is a 3D-tensor that is a the first element of this group. Here the first number `1` means that you group is only composed of one 3D-tensor. Then, you guess that a 3D-tensor is a group of 2D-tensor (also called matrices). Here your 3D-tensor is composed of `224` 2D-tensors (the second number). Then each 2D-tensor is composed of `224` 1D-tensors (vectors) of lenght 3.

In your particular case you can also (more simply) view your data as a group composed of one RGB image of size 224*224. Each pixel has 3 values (red, green, blue intensity).

Answer (score 0):

Python NumPy numpy.shape() function finds the shape of an array. By shape, we mean that it helps in finding the dimensions of an array. It returns the shape in the form of a tuple because we cannot alter a tuple just like we cannot alter the dimensions of an array.

**Example Codes: numpy.shape() to Pass a Simple Array**

We will pass a simple one-dimensional array now.

```
import numpy as np 
   
a = np.array([89, 34, 56, 87, 90, 23, 45, 12, 65, 78, 9, 34, 12, 11, 2, 65, 78, 82, 28, 78]) 
dimensions = np.shape(a) 
print(dimensions)
```

Output:
(20,)

The output shows that the array is one-dimensional and contains 20 elements.

**Example Codes: numpy.shape() to Pass a Multi-Dimensional Array**

```
import numpy as np 
   
a = np.array([[11, 12, 5], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12], [12,15,8], [34, 78, 90]]) 
dimensions = np.shape(a) 
print(dimensions)
```

Output:

```
(5, 3)
```

Note that the output tuple now contains two integer elements. It shows that the array contains five rows and three columns.

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning, images are loaded in batch/bulk for faster loading, so the first value means "loaded in batch".

```
# you can read like this:
(batch, image_width, image_height, RGB_dims) = (1,224,224,3)
```

Comment: Thank you but one more question, what is the use of RGB_dims?
I guess the dims here mean dimensions, but did not get the exact meaning.

Comment: If image is Grayscale( black & white)  so `(1,224,224,1)` .     But, color images are made by mixing Red,Green,Blue  ie. 3 colors so. `(1,224,224,3)`